# Custom x-axis ticks values in ggplot2 facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the group labels in a facet plot in ggplot2. This code

```
data = tidyr::gather(data = iris, variable, value, -Species)

ggplot(data, aes(y = value, x = variable, fill = Species)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = "dodge", notch = TRUE) +
  ylab("median(x)") +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free", ncol = 2)
```

produces
[image]

I want the x-axis tick labels to represent each **Species name** instead of the variable the respective sub-plot is being grouped by (which is also repeating whats already in the sub-plots title). Any idea on how I can achieve that? I've been searching the web all over but could not find any valuable information on that.

best regards,
Andi

**Update**

Henrik gave the right answer, I'd have to change the proper `aes` feature. Thanks!

Comment: Replace `x = variable` with `x = Species` in your `aes`?

Comment: Thanks, looks as if I have to recap ggplots grammar!

Comment: there is also an argument called `labeller` in `facet_wrap`... don't know if it can be used but might worth a look